# Extract value from observable in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I have `user$: Observable<User>;` in my `AuthService`. I hace `OrderService` too. I want to make request based on User.id (Getting all users orders).

This my function:

```
getUserOrders() {
    let id;
    this.authService.user$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => id = data.uid);
    return this.firestore.collection('orders', ref => ref.where("purchaserId","==", id)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => {
        return changes.map(a => {
          let data = a.payload.doc.data() as Order;
          data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return data;
      });
      })
    );
  }
```

The problem is this line:

```
let id;
   this.authService.user$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => id = data.uid);
```

Because id stays undefined when return statement is called. So i get error `Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was undefined.`

I know working with async pipe is convenient in html. But i think using observable in typescript makes it harder. I think better solution would be to change `user$: Observable<User>` to `user: User`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is asynchronous :

```js
this.authService.user$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => id = data.uid);
```

So `id` isn't initialised yet with `data.uid` when **firestore.collection** is called.

You can change `getUserOrders`  to :

```
return this.authService.user$.pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap(({uid}) => {
    return return this.firestore.collection('orders', ref => 
      ref.where("purchaserId","==", uid)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(changes => {
          return changes.map(a => {
            let data = a.payload.doc.data() as Order;
            data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return data;
          });
        })
      );
    })
  )
```

After getting the id, it switchs the returned observable to the firestore.collection with the provided id.